# Contour: Saving dataset with older version

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I am doing analysis in Contour using the older version of the data. Now, I want to save the result as dataset but saving data with "Save as dataset" button saves latest version of the data. Please suggest how I save the result with older version.

Comment: This is currently not possible via the UI. There is a private API in Catalog that can be hit to perform this task, but we don't want to answer it publicly at the moment. I would recommend reaching out to internal support to ask for it. Once there is an answer we can share publicly we'll post it.